# Is there an adjective for zero?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe three situations regarding an amount

- Above 0
- 0
- Below 0

For above zero i would say "a positive amount", and for below zero i would say "a negative amount". What would I say for an amount of zero?

Example:

> I received a bill for a __________ amount.

Comment: Just say "a zero amount".

Comment: "I received a bill for _no_ amount"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although OED¹ (and its little brother Oxford Dictionaries Online) does not list *zero* as an adjective, Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary does:

> 2. **zero** /ˈziroʊ/ *adjective*
>
>    : not any
>
>    - The economy experienced zero [=no] inflation last year.
>    - (informal) He has zero [=no] chance of winning. = His chances of winning are zero. [=nonexistent]
>
> [MWLD](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/zero#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_zero_2)

Just say "a zero amount".

---

¹ The OED entry for *zero* was first published in 1921 and has not been fully updated. The omission of *zero* as an adjective is a little surprising; it seems to me to have passed mere colloquial status.

Comment: And *non-zero* is a very common adjectival phrase, so I think the use of *zero* as an adjective is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I have heard *non-non-zero* used in conversation, but I find no one using it in print.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer to your inquiry is as follows: "I received a bill for a null amount."

> **null** [nuhl]
>   adjective
>
> 1. without value, effect, consequence, or significance.
> 2. being or amounting to nothing; nil; lacking; nonexistent.
> 3. *Mathematics*.
>       a. empty.
>       b. of measure zero.
> 4. being or amounting to zero.

<sub>Source: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/null)</sub>

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be greatly strengthened if you could *demonstrate* the use of *null* here, for instance by finding examples in quality writing, or adding a dictionary reference. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Null is a poor substitute for zero in this case, because null can mean unknown, and in this case that would be a more likely meaning because if one means zero, use zero. Using null would be like saying "I received a bill where the amount was left blank."